# Run xUnit test with Team Build 2010

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, xunit.net

I need to **configure Team Build Server (TFS 2010) to run xUnit tests** as well as MSTests. Some information I've found is the next urls:

http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2009/08/25/configuring-team-build-using-xunit.aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/mehfuz/archive/2009/09/05/configuring-team-build-using-xunit-from-client-update.aspx

Every post on the web is saying that I need to modify / configure team build server, or `TeamBuildTypes` directory (btw. I don't see it in my Team Explorer). But my problem is that Team buid is in corporate network and I'm not able to configure it in my way.

So, **my question**: Is there any ability to configure team Build 2010 to run xUnit tests continuously? How can I configure it only from client side to run xUnit tests?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those articles are talking about TFS 2008 not 2010.  In TFS 2010 the build technology changed significantly.

What you want to do is customize the TFS Build workflow file (DefaultTemplate.xaml) that will exist in the BuildProcessTemplates directory in your source control.

You need to add an InvokeProcess activity that will execute the appropriate command-line command to run xUnit for you.

Here's some links that might help you out:

http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2012/02/01/handling-warnings-and-errors-with-invokeprocess-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx